# Problemas com Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema em captar uma entrada de texto em uma caixa de diálogo no AndroidStudio. Quero receber a quantidade de um produto e adicionar em um `ArrayList`, porém a função não aguarda a inserção no `EditText` que adicionei dentro da caixa de diálogo e atribui o valor 0 pra minha variável de retorno.

Eis o código onde invoco o método:

```
/*Método que captura o click do garçon em determinado produto e depois pega a quantidade */
public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener Dialogo(){
    return(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Produtos cafe = new Produtos();
                    cafe.setId(0);
                    cafe.setQuantidade(Caixa_Dialogo("Café"));
                    cafe.setTempo_preparo(2);
                    pro_pedidos.add(cafe);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Produtos suco = new Produtos();
                    suco.setId(1);
                    suco.setQuantidade( Caixa_Dialogo("Suco"));
                    suco.setTempo_preparo(10);
                    pro_pedidos.add(suco);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Produtos refrigerante = new Produtos();
                    refrigerante.setId(2);
                    refrigerante.setQuantidade( Caixa_Dialogo("Refrigerante"));
                    refrigerante.setTempo_preparo(10);
                    pro_pedidos.add(refrigerante);
                    break;
            }//switch

        }//onItemClick.
    });//return


}//Dialogo
```

Este é o método que cria a caixa:

```
/*Método que retorna uma quantidade digitada pelo garçon em uma caixa de diálogo*/
public int Caixa_Dialogo(String item){

    AlertDialog.Builder caixa = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
    caixa.setTitle("Seleção de quantidade");
    caixa.setMessage(item+" selecionado. Digite a quantidade que o cliente deseja:");

    /*Construção do TextEdit.*/
    final EditText entrada = new EditText(Main2Activity.this);
    entrada.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    caixa.setView(entrada);

    caixa.show();

    caixa.setNeutralButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

            quantidade = Integer.parseInt(entrada.getText().toString());

        }
    });//setNeutralButton

    caixa.show();



    return quantidade;
}
```

Comment: Acredito que a confusão aqui é a comparação do Dialog do swing com o dialog do android. Acontece que ao chamar um dialog, o método não para e aguarda retorno. No Android você exibe o dialog e a execução do método que o chamou prossegue normalmente. Terás que usar eventos para capturar do valor quando o dialog fechar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture a informação após a ação de click no botão do Dialog, atente-se também para o fato de o usuário tentar confirmar a ação com o campo vazio, senão irá disparar um exceção ao tentar converter para int. Como não é possível retornar um valor a partir da implementação de um evento, crie um método que executará um algoritmo que faça o que você deseja. Abaixo segue um modelo com o que eu disse:

```
public void Caixa_Dialogo(String item){

AlertDialog.Builder caixa = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
caixa.setTitle("Seleção de quantidade");
caixa.setMessage(item+" selecionado. Digite a quantidade que o cliente deseja:");

/*Construção do TextEdit.*/

final EditText entrada = new EditText(Main2Activity.this);
entrada.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
caixa.setView(entrada);

caixa.show();

caixa.setNeutralButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (!entrada.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            quantidade= Integer.parseInt(entrada.getText().toString());
            faca(quantidade);
        }
    }
});//setNeutralButton

caixa.show();
```

}